# spring boot mvc jackson format bigdecimal

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, bigdecimal

the BigDecimal value 0.02, serialize as 0.0199999...

I can format in the getter method, but I need do that in every entity.

Is there a way the config BigDecimal serialize format globally?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a derivative class, override the default methods to implement the behavior you prefer, and use that class instead throughout your application.

Comment: This is the problem, I have to do in every entity class

Answer (score 0):

How do you constrict your BigDecimal value ? Do you use BigDecimal(String) or BigDecimal(double) for example ?

Comment: prefer double, and string is ok.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)   - check care side effects of double.